# Odoo14 How to use a variable in template

Tags: python, odoo

I'm looking for solutions everywhere, please help.

```
    <t t-set="product_image" t-value="aggregated_lines[line]['product_image']"/>
    <t t-set="product_name" t-value="aggregated_lines[line]['name']"/>
    <td style="float:left;width:30%;text-align: center;">
       <img t-att-src="data:image/*;base64,{{product_image}}"
                                t-att-alt="{{product_name}}" />
    </td>
```

I cannot use variables, if I use aggregated_lines[line]['product_image'] directly
Will report an hash set error

Comment: Can you please elaborate what's behind `aggregated_lines` and its structure and also what's behind `line`. Thank you

Comment: please add context -- what is the full python code that is generating this response?

Comment: aggregated_lines is find from template id stock.stock_report_delivery_aggregated_move_lines

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use image url instead of it's base64 encoded binary content? Use this url format `/web/image/{record_model}/{record_id}/{image_field}`.
Assuming your model is `product.template`, the code will be like this.

```
<img t-att-src="'/web/image/product.template/{}/product_image'.format(product_id)" t-att-alt="product_name"/>
```

You also don't need to use `{{}}` inside `t-att-*=""`. You are using the syntax for `t-attf-*=""` for `t-att-*=""`. Notice the extra **f**. So if you want to use the image's binary content your code must be like below.

```
<img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{product_image}}"
                            t-attf-alt="{{product_name}}" />
```